# customizing ag-grid to set a max number of selectable rows

Tags: angularjs, datatable, row, selection, ag-grid

I am trying to customize a data table using `ag-grid` in my Angular 1.5 based project. The customization is that the user is allowed to select a maximum number of rows in the table, for example, the maximum is 2.

I have the following code by using `node.setSelected(false)` that I found in the documentation page [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-selection/index.php), but I got the error: `node.setSelected is not a function` when the selection exceeds the maximum of 2.

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    onRowSelected: onRowSelected
};


function onRowSelected(event) {
                var curSelectedNode = event.node;
                var selectionCounts = vm.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes().length;
                if (selectionCounts > 2) {
                    var oldestNode = vm.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes()[0]; // get the first node, to be popped out
                    oldestNode.setSelected(false); // causes the above 'not a function' error
                 }       
            }
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong with ag-grid for its `setSelected()` API? or any better way to do this customization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it turns out that `setSelected(false)` method is outdated in its current `ag-grid` API, and I found that I can use `deselectIndex()` method to deselect the oldest node:

```
if (selectionCounts > 2) {
    vm.gridOptions.api.deselectIndex(0, true); // This works!
}
```

Hope this will help someone else in the future!

Answer (score 1):

```
var columnDefs =[{
                       headerName: 'Name',
                       field: 'name',
                       width: 108,
                       minLength: 1,
                       maxLength: 20,
                       editable: true
}]
```

- Modify prototype in file .js

```
TextCellEditor.prototype.init = function (params) {
        var eInput = this.getGui();
        var startValue;

        // Set min & max length
        if (params.column.colDef.maxLength)
            eInput.maxLength = params.column.colDef.maxLength;
        if (params.column.colDef.minLength)
            eInput.minLength = params.column.colDef.minLength;

        // cellStartedEdit is only false if we are doing fullRow editing
        if (params.cellStartedEdit) {
            this.focusAfterAttached = true;
            var keyPressBackspaceOrDelete = params.keyPress === constants_1.Constants.KEY_BACKSPACE
                || params.keyPress === constants_1.Constants.KEY_DELETE;
            if (keyPressBackspaceOrDelete) {
                startValue = '';
            }
            else if (params.charPress) {
                startValue = params.charPress;
            }
            else {
                startValue = params.value;
                if (params.keyPress !== constants_1.Constants.KEY_F2) {
                    this.highlightAllOnFocus = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            this.focusAfterAttached = false;
            startValue = params.value;
        }
        if (utils_1.Utils.exists(startValue)) {
            eInput.value = startValue;
        }
        this.addDestroyableEventListener(eInput, 'keydown', function (event) {
            var isNavigationKey = event.keyCode === constants_1.Constants.KEY_LEFT || event.keyCode === constants_1.Constants.KEY_RIGHT;
            if (isNavigationKey) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    };
```